# Comparar letras en dos string

Tags: c#

La tarea es que compare dos `string` y saque un porcentaje de acuerdo a la similitud.

Un ejemplo seria

```
String palabra1 = "Hola Mundo";
String palabra2 = "ola mudo"
```

debería mostrarme en consola las letras que no contiene palabra2 con respecto a palabra1 y y mostrarme el porcentaje según las letras que si encontró.

Como aclaración las letras deben de compararse de acuerdo al orden de palabra1 ya que palabra2 podría contener las letras de palabra1 pero desordenada.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo. Referencia: [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Tambien, ademas del codigo, tenes que mostrar resultado esperado y resultado obtenido.

Comment: Gracias por las aclaracion que tendre en cuenta, es que no se como empezar para poder mostrar algun avance, estaba solicitando orientacion.

Comment: Debees intentar algo, y en base a los errores y problemas que eso te genere te podemos ayudar.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un código que creo que se adecua a lo que estas buscando en los comentarios explique que hace cada línea

```
//Primera frase
string phrase = "Hola Mundo esto es una prueba";
//Segunda frase
string phrase2 = "ola Mundo con una simple prueba";
//Separo las palabras de la primera frase
string[] words = phrase.Split(' ');
//Separo las palabras de la segunda frase
string[] words2 = phrase2.Split(' ');
//Aqui almaceno las palabras que son diferentes en la segunda frase con respecto a la primera
List<string> differents = new List<string>();
//Contador de las similitudes
int equals = 0;
//Recorro las palabras de la primera frase
for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    //Si estoy entre los indices de las palabras de la segunda frase (Para evitar buscar en indices que no existan)
    if(i < words2.Length)
    {
        //Si en la posición actual las palabras de las dos frases son diferentes...
        if(words2[i] != words[i])
        {
            //Agrego la palabra de la frase dos a la lista
            differents.Add(words2[i]);
        }
        //Sino incremento el contador de similitud
        else
        {
            equals++;
        }
    }
}

//Obtengo el total de palabras basado en cual de los arreglos de palabras sea más grande
float total = (words.Length > words2.Length) ? words.Length : words2.Length;
//Calculo el porciento de similitud
float percent = equals / total * 100f;

Console.WriteLine("Similitud: {0:N1}%", percent);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", differents.ToArray()));
```

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque es una pregunta flagrantemente fuera de tópico.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2884/)

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con flagratemente fuera de topico

Comment: Leiste el link que esta en el comentario?

Comment: Ya ok me imagino ke sea por el ultimo punto del link donde piden que hagan algo sin explicar lo que han hecho

Comment: Exactamente. Esta explicitamente aclarado que ese tipo de preguntas no son validas y es un motivo de cierre.